# Why does the same Linq-to-SQL query consume much more CPU time on the database server for a different project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have a **legacy .Net 4 project (name it "A")** which uses Linq-to-SQL to query a database and
I have **another .Net 4 project (name it "B")** with similiar but not the same code which queries the same database as "A".

Both projects:

- are C# projects {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
- use the same assemblies (version v4.0.30319, same folder)

  - System.dll
  - System.Data.dll
  - System.Data.Linq.dll

The auto-generated [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is specific for each project but instantiated the same way:

- same connection string using SQL authentication
- both DataContext set their [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the default to 60 seconds
- all other configuration options for the DataContext are the defaults

The way the Linq query is constructed is not exactly the same for the projects but the resulting Linq query is the same.
The generated (T-)SQL select statement is the same as well! *(monitored and verified the SQL handles on the db server)*

The database server is:

- Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 2005 x64 (9.00.4035.00)
- Operating System: Microsoft Server 2003 R2 SP2 x64

If ran the monitored [CPU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) time (on db server) increased drastically for the query of project "A" and a command timeout exception was thrown.
*(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired)*

On the other hand the query of "B" executed within seconds *(around 3)*.
I was able to reproduce the behavior by calling the code of "A" with the same parameters again *(no changes to code or database)*.
"B" even executed within seconds at the same time "A" was increasing its CPU time.

**Regrettably after a co-worker created the indices anew I can no longer reprocude the behavior.**
The same co-worker mentioned that the query ran fast "last month" (although no code changed from "last month"...).

I debugged the code for both projects - both DataContext instances looked alike.
The db server process' sql handle contains the same SQL statement.
But "A" threw a timeout exception and "B" executed within seconds - repetitive!

**Why does the same Linq-to-SQL query consume much more CPU time on the database server for project "A" as for "B"?**

To be precise: If the query runs "slow" due to reasons - repetitive - how can the same query run faster just because it is called by another Linq-to-SQL code?

Can there be side effects I do not know of (yet)?
Are there some instance values of the DataContext I have to look at runtime specifically?

By the way: the SQL statement - via SSMS - does use the same query plan on each run.

For the sake of completeness I have linked a sample of:

- the [C# code](http://pastebin.com/JPppy0N7) fragments of project "B" *(the SqlRequest.GetQuery part looks alike for both projects)*
- the [SQL file](http://pastebin.com/NjpBTQCw) contains the appropriate database schema
- the database [execution plan](http://pastebin.com/AQhvGwvM)

Please keep in mind that I cannot disclose the full db schema nor the code nor the actual data I am querying against.
(The SQL tables have other columns beside the named ones and the C# code is a bit more complex because the Linq query is constructed conditionally.)

### Update - more insight at run-time

Some properties of both `DataContext` instances:

```
Log = null;
Transaction = null;
CommandTimeout = 60;
Connection: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
```

The SqlConnection was created from a connection string like that (both cases):

```
"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=sourceDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"
```

There are no explicit SqlCommands being run to pass `SET` options to the database session. Neither contains the inline TVF `SET` options.

Comment: Are you sure the parameters used in the queries are the same? When I see this it is usually because a query plan is generated appropriately for parameter X, but when used with parameter Y the plan is sub-optimal due to cardinality differences in the underlying values.

Comment: are the connection strings identical? (are things like MARS or async enabled/disabled in both, for example?) is the *transaction* state identical for both? this could be explicit transactions, but also ambient/implicit transactions (`TransactionScope`), and either LTM or DTC. Is the isolation-level the same in both? Are the `SET` options the same in both? etc etc

Comment: I can tell you from the plan things that MIGHT be an issue. Table valued functions that are multi-statement. udf_get_category_with_dependencies Is that a multi-statement function?

Comment: @RobEpstein Yes, I had both queries run by myself in debugger, the statement parameters where the same. I even ran the SQL statement itself in SSMS with the passed parameters to verify the database itself and got a fast response.

Comment: @SeanLange No, the TVF is inline, see my linked SQL file.

Comment: @MarcGravell Connection String is the same, as said, debugger break just before the query against the server and stepped into the `Connection` property of the `DataContext` instance. I have not used a `TransactionScope` manually but Linq-to-SQL should use its own. For the `SET` options: is there a way to debug or profile them? Because I have not used any `SET` options explicitly.

Comment: There is no way two equal queries take different times use the SQL Server Profiler and see the exact SQL that is being run and it will be clear what the issue is, probably A is doing multiple requests one for each row in the result of a previously run query and B returns everything in one go.

Comment: Are the target platforms the same in both projects?  E.g. did you build one in Release Mode and the Other in Debug mode by any chance?

The debug mode code would run a lot slower.

Can you pull out the queries that are running and run them in SQL Management Studio to see if it's a DB Query Issue or a Project/Code issue?

Answer (score 10):

You need to [run a trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047(v=sql.90).aspx) on SQL Server instead of debugging this from the C# side.  This will show you everything both `A` and `B` are executing on the server.  The execution plan does you no good because it's precisely that - just a plan.  You want to see the *exact* statements and their *actual* performance metrics.

In the rare event you were to tell me that both `SELECT` statements are *exactly* the same but had vastly different performance I would be virtually certain they are running under different [transaction isolation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).  A single SQL command is an implicit transaction even if you aren't explicitly creating any.

If for whatever reason the trace doesn't make it clear you should post the commands being ran along with their metrics.

**Note:** running a trace has some performance overhead cost to it so I would try to keep the timeframe small or run during off-peak if possible.

Comment: Include the "Audit Login" event and include TextData column. This will reveal (what I think of as) a bunch of "stealth" SET settings. Compare and contrast the connections used by the two queries.

Comment: +1 for the Profiler Trace - I forgot that completely. The server is the production one and due to the performance impact it will take some time to get a window for a profiler session. @PhilipKelley: I will include the options, thank you. Maybe I will have a light bulb moment...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will check LazyLoadingEnabled="true" in your "A" project edmx-file .

If LazyLoadingEnabled="true": In case of lazy loading, related objects (child objects) are not automatically loaded with its parent object until they are requested. Default LINQ supports lazy loading.

IF LazyLoadingEnabled="false": In case of eager loading, related objects (child objects) are loaded automatically with its parent object. To use Eager loading you need to use Include() method.

Comment: If you mean the counterpart [DeferredLoadingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.deferredloadingenabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then it is set to `true` - by default. If not: I am using **Linq-to-SQL not the Entity Framework**.